# MS Access 2007 Form Logic

Tags: forms, ms-access, lookup

This is my first post on Stack. I've been reading for a while and learned a lot. Thanks to all those who share on this site.

My office runs still runs MS Access 2007 and I was tasked with creating a database even though I had no experience doing so. I read "The Missing Manual for Access 2007", another book that I can't remember the name of, multiple posts on this site and Microsoft's and can't find the solution to what I need to do.

Issue: I want to have two fields on a form referring to the same table, each with look ups but want the second field's options to be dependent on the first. For example, I want the first field for "Region" to list options to select 1 2 3 or 4. If someone chooses 1, I want the second field only listed offices that are in Region 1. This doesn't seem like it should wildly complicated but I cannot figure out how to do it.

I have tried using the expression builder to create nested IIf functions, filtering queries, macros and a few other things but don't have the depth of knowledge to make any of them accomplish what I'm looking to do.

Is there a way to accomplish this easily without VBA? Or if VBA is the only way, can someone point me to a good code that I hopefully figure out and edit for this purpose?

Thank you for any help and advice. Please let me know if I left out any useful information

Steve

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwWjz.png)

Comment: Search this site for cascading combobox.

Comment: Perfect, that's it! Thank you very much!